# Left join on one or the other column without table-scanning

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sybase-ase-15.7

I have this huge sql with a lot of left joins. Mostly on the tables primary key, so no problem. On one table though, my key could exist in either one column or the other. 
Syntax-wise that is no problem:

```
LEFT JOIN table2 blk ON (t.rid=blk.transact OR t.rid=blk.transactchild)
```

I have created two indices on table2, one for each of the keys, but my Sybase ASE 15.7 decides to table scan in stead. So I tried creating a single index with both of the keys and forcing it in the join, but that didn't help on performance. Showplan indicates, that the index is being used, but a scan takes forever. Is there a better way to join on either one or the other column?

Answer (score 2):

When you have two separate indexes on `transact` and on `transactchild` the server can't use them efficiently when searching for `(t.rid=blk.transact OR t.rid=blk.transactchild)`.

The classic way to handle this type of `OR` search is to split it into two simple searches and then `UNION` results together.

So, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT ....
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN table2 blk ON (t.rid=blk.transact)

UNION

SELECT ....
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN table2 blk ON (t.rid=blk.transactchild)
```

In this case individual simple query should be able to use corresponding index, but the extra `UNION` step can be quite expensive, especially if it requires a sort.

If your data is such that you know that `UNION ALL` would produce correct result, then use `UNION ALL`, which is much more efficient than `UNION`. `UNION` eliminates duplicates, which is expensive. `UNION ALL` simply outputs results of two queries one after another.

If values in `blk.transact` do not overlap with values in `blk.transactchild`, then you can use `UNION ALL`.